# How to deploy MVC application in 2003 server IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

I was deploying an MVC application in IIS resides in 2003 server.I don't have Visual studio installed or web deploy rather .net framework and required stuffs are installed over there.I just created a virtual directory under default website and mapped my website file by using alias.Then configured default application pool with corresponding framework .Then when i browsed i was not able to throw web application. Can.Can any body suggest me the simple steps i required to install MVC application in IIS over windows 2003 server. Remember i don't have webdeploy or visual studio installed rather than the .net frame work .When i googled every where they are mentioning about web deploy or one click publish  from visual studio

**UPDATE**

i have VS installed on my system,if you can guide me something which i can create a package in my system and deploy it in web server is appreciated.I came from winform background where we create setup file for installation

Comment: Do you have VS installed on your development machine?

Comment: @jasen yes i have VS2012 installed on my system,if you can guide me something which i can create a package in my system and deploy it in web server is appreciated.I came from winform background where we create setup file for installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio lets you publish to File System. I set this up on my dev machine to a specific folder (outside of my project). Then I right-click on my project to publish and my project files get copied to this folder.

1. Right-click project > Publish...
2. New Profile (File System)
3. Set path
4. Publish

Now all the required files are in a correct folder structure. This just needs to be copied (FTP) to the deployment location.

For a new website:

1. In IIS Default Web Site > create a new web application.
2. Set alias and path to virtual directory
3. Set App Pool
4. Copy my published directory to the virtual directory

What it looks like on the webserver

```
C:/Web/MyMvcProj
            /bin
            /Content
            /Scripts
            /Views
            Global.asax
            Web.config
```

Comment: for MVC do i have to enable any additional things,how the start up page is managed since mvc has routing system

Comment: Check the path matches your alias: `/MyMvcProj` and my root url would be `www.domain.com/MyMvcProj/Home/Index`.