# Do i need to install asp.net mvc4 on iis server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web-deployment, odp.net

I am going to deploy my application tomorrow ,so i have few questions.I want to deploy asp.net mvc4 application on 2003 server where .net framework 4.0 is installed.My question is do i need to install asp.net mvc4 also there.Or if i copy the dll responsible for mvc in to that system is sufficient?
another question is i am using entityframework and oracle database so using ODP.NET, if this is the case do i need to install ODP.NET over there or just copying DLL system.dataaccess dll is sufficient?
Rest all i follow this two links will it work

The two links are http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/
[How to deploy MVC application in 2003 server IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088285/how-to-deploy-mvc-application-in-2003-server-iis)

**UPDATE**
 today i tried and unfortunately i came to know that the framework which i was running .net 4.5 will not be supported in 2003.I made my project in to .net 4.0 and everything working fine in local system,but remote system lot of errors are coming.Method not found etc. I came to know that i have to degrade EF 5.0 to 4.4 i did it like replaced dll and changed one line begin with section but no luck as of now.I have to change somewhere else also.Do you know any proper mechanism which i need to carry forward for this?

Answer (score 3):

No need to install anything explicitly except .Net 4.0. All you need is make sure that all dependencies (assemblies) of your application i.e. MVC, ODP.Net etc are present in bin directory of your application. Also make sure that ASP.Net v4.0 Web service extension is enabled in IIS.

Steps to enable web service extension.

1. Open IIS 6.0 Manager
2. Click Web Service Extensions
3. Enable ASP.NET 4.0 
   Check below screenshot.
   [image]

Comment: how to enable ASP.Net v4.0 Web service extension  in IIS?

Comment: .One more question about creating virtual directory  is do i need to add application or add virtual directory and then convert to application(i dont know whether it is there in 2003 server)

Comment: Add it as application. If you have virtual directory created already then on property page of VDir you will find Create button. IF button is remove then your application is already created.

Comment: thats great , tomorrow i will deploy and update you.Once success i will make this as answer :)

Comment: today i tried and unfortunately i came to know that the framework which i was running .net 4.5 will not be supported in 2003.I made my project in to .net 4.0 and everything working fine in local system,but remote system lot of errors are coming.Method not found etc. I came to know that i have to degrade EF 5.0 to 4.4 i did it like replaced dll and changed one line in webconfig begin with section but no luck as of now.I have to change somewhere else also.Do you know any proper mechanism which i need to carry forward for this?